# Выполнение сочетания клавиш нажатием на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

Посоветуйте, как реализовать сочетание клавиш нажатием на input button через js.
Например, у меня есть некий `<input id="learn" type="button" value="learning" OnClick="learn();">` и функция в js, которую он запускает (сама же функция, запускает другой файл js)

```
`function learn() {
    let learn = document.createElement('script');
    learn.src = "scripts/learning.js";
    document.head.append(learn);
}`
```

И нужно, например, эмулировать сочетание ctrl+shift+t, когда нажимается input

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста более детально вопрос

Comment: Расшифруйте вопрос. Вам нужно при нажатии определенного сочетания клавиш эмулировать `click` на кнопке или наоборот - при нажатии на кнопку эмулировать нажатие сочетания клавиш?

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку эмулировать сочетание клавиш.

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/587042

Comment: Спасибо
Похоже, мне стоит поучиться гуглить лучше

Answer (score 2):

При нажатии на кнопку эмулируем нажатие сочетания клавиш <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd>

```js
const inp = document.querySelector('input');
inp.addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.dispatchEvent(
    new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
      keyCode: 13,
      ctrlKey: true
    })
  );
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 13) {
    console.log('Hi there');
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Click me">
```

Comment: Спасибо, что уделили время